# Storefront overwrite customize register?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I am creating a child theme using the storefront as a parent theme so far I am doing well, I am trying to create a website where I can change the basic aspects of the style of the website like background-color, custom text in `wp-admin/customize.php.`

I know I can add more options using [customize_register](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/customize_register/) , but the storefront theme has its own action hook for that, in fact I already added my own action hook to enable more options see below

[image]

as you can see the problem is that it creates another "footer" option, is there any way to overwrite or insert custom options, within the existing "footer" option of the parent theme?

here the code im using to insert options

```
function footer_customize_register( $custom_vars ) {
    $custom_vars ->add_section(
         'layout_section',
                array(
                     'title'       => __( 'Footer', 'pre' ),
                     'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
                     'description' => __( 'Allows you to edit your theme layout.', 'pre' ),
                     'priority'    => 25,
                )
    );
    $custom_vars -> add_setting('pre_layout_options[address_text]', array(
         'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
         'type'       => 'option',
         'default'    => '000 7th St NW',
    ));
    $custom_vars -> add_control('pre_layout_options[address_text]', array(
         'label'   => 'adress',
         'section' => 'layout_section',
         'type'    => 'text',
    ));
    $custom_vars -> add_setting('pre_layout_options[phone_text]', array(
         'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
         'type'       => 'option',
         'default'    => '01234-567',
    ));
    $custom_vars -> add_control('pre_layout_options[phone_text]', array(
         'label'   => 'ZIP code',
         'section' => 'layout_section',
         'type'    => 'text',
    ));
    $custom_vars -> add_setting('pre_layout_options[VAT]', array(
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'type'       => 'option',
        'default'    => '00.000.000/0000-00',
    ));
    $custom_vars -> add_control('pre_layout_options[VAT]', array(
            'label'   => 'VAT number',
            'section' => 'layout_section',
            'type'    => 'text',
    ));
    $custom_vars -> add_setting('pre_layout_options[Location]', array(
            'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
            'type'       => 'option',
            'default'    => 'Centro',
    ));
    $custom_vars -> add_control('pre_layout_options[Location]', array(
            'label'   => 'Location',
            'section' => 'layout_section',
            'type'    => 'text',
    ));
    
}

add_action('customize_register', 'footer_customize_register');
```

the source code is from [here](https://matthewgladney.com/blog/featured/using-customize_register-to-make-better-themes/)

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far.

Comment: hi @Bhautik, thanks for your answer, i believe the best option is to redo the question and insert the code i am using to enable the options.

Comment: @Bhautik I believe these functions are located in `inc\customizer\class-storefront-customizer.php` I was studying the storefront theme and found this code block inside this folder that starts with
`$ wp_customize-> add_control (new WP_Customize_Color_Control ($ wp_customize, 'storefront_footer_background_color', array ();`

Comment: I will back to you tomorrow. I am getting late here.

Comment: @Bhautik thank you very much appreciate for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `section` you need to add `storefront_footer` and add `priority` to change position. check below code.

```
function footer_customize_register( $custom_vars ) {

    $custom_vars -> add_setting('pre_layout_options[address_text]', array(
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'type'       => 'option',
        'default'    => '000 7th St NW',
    ));
    $custom_vars -> add_control('pre_layout_options[address_text]', array(
        'label'   => 'adress',
        'section' => 'storefront_footer',
        'type'    => 'text',
        'priority' => 50,
    ));
    $custom_vars -> add_setting('pre_layout_options[phone_text]', array(
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'type'       => 'option',
        'default'    => '01234-567',
    ));
    $custom_vars -> add_control('pre_layout_options[phone_text]', array(
        'label'   => 'ZIP code',
        'section' => 'storefront_footer',
        'type'    => 'text',
        'priority' => 60,
    ));
    $custom_vars -> add_setting('pre_layout_options[VAT]', array(
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'type'       => 'option',
        'default'    => '00.000.000/0000-00',
    ));
    $custom_vars -> add_control('pre_layout_options[VAT]', array(
        'label'   => 'VAT number',
        'section' => 'storefront_footer',
        'type'    => 'text',
        'priority' => 70,
    ));
    $custom_vars -> add_setting('pre_layout_options[Location]', array(
        'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
        'type'       => 'option',
        'default'    => 'Centro',
    ));
    $custom_vars -> add_control('pre_layout_options[Location]', array(
        'label'   => 'Location',
        'section' => 'storefront_footer',
        'type'    => 'text',
        'priority' => 80,
    ));
    
}

add_action('customize_register', 'footer_customize_register');
```

Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your support this works beautifully, so basically if i want to change the others options such as header options all i have to do is set a priority?

Comment: Welcome... For header use `'section' => 'storefront_header',`

Comment: thank you i tried and work on the header too